# .NET MSHTML PIA causes very slow app startup time on some machines

Tags: .net, wpf, mshtml

I have a .NET 3.5 WPF application that references and uses the Microsoft.MSHTML primary interop assembly. On my dev machine warm startup time for the app is quite fast, usually < 1 sec. However, on production machines it is ~10 seconds (totally unacceptable).

I did some research and found out that their are actually two versions of the MSHTML PIA floating around out there, one that is fully signed and one that is not fully signed or something like that. I retrieved the fully signed one from the GAC on my dev machine to put on production machines, rather than what I had been doing which was putting the one from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies` on the production machines. At first this solved the problem, apparently it was some security issue with the 'not fully signed' PIA having to be 'verified' or some such ms nonsense like that.

Now, however it seems that even this is not working and the app is stil taking ~10 seconds to load (warm), almost all of which is due to the MSHTML reference.

I have full control over both the app and the configuration (system image) of all the production machines it will run on, so I can change anything I need to get this working (BTW everything is running Windows 7 with IE 9).

Apparently it is possible to generate your own mshtml interop wrapper, but I'm not sure how to do this or if it would even help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply add the following lines to my app.config file:

```
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```